# Handle non-REST logic in Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, crud, api-design, web-development-server

For example, let's say I have a Post resource.
With `GET /posts` I retrieve all posts (`index` action). What if I want to retrieve trending posts (posts with a lot of likes in the last 24 hours)? Should I implement the logic in the `index` action (through a parameter), or should I implement a new action `trending` that responds to a new endpoint `GET /trending`, making the API non-REST?

Note: I read [this article](https://karolgalanciak.com/blog/2016/01/24/how-to-handle-non-crud-logic-in-your-api/) and I understand the parameter way, but I can't figure out how adding an extra endpoint works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do both. I would opt for the new action. But you can pass an extra param as well in a link:

`link_to posts_path(trending: true)`

In your controller you can then check if `params[:trending].present?` and then only pass to the posts variable `@posts` the trending posts.

You can also assign the trending indicator to a variable that will be passed to the index view so that you can adapt the layout (change header from "posts" to "trending posts") with `if params[:trending].present? then @trending = true end`

Creating a new action makes controllers and views less cluttered with conditions (`if ...`)

By the way, creating a new action is still a REST logic if you make it a `GET` query. If your new action was about updating a post it would need be a `PATCH`query

Comment: Thank you, I thought that adding an action with a different name would be non REST. Why is it RESTful?

Comment: It's Restful because Post is used to create a model instance, patch to update it etc.. it's more about your http query. CRUD is only about the 4 actions (create read update delete) but it is not a problem to add more actions. It is about your app design and maintenance really. Creating a new action needs a new view but it's clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Problably you have the `resource :posts` inside your `routes.rb`. This is the place you have to add the new endpoint. In rails the route to the new action.

You have

```
resources :posts
```

You should have

```
resources :posts do
  get 'trending', on: :collection
end
```

Now you can see all routes that rails generate to you `line, index, show, create, update...` **and more one `trending`**

```
/posts/trending
```

You can have a look here: [Rails guides add restful](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#adding-more-restful-actions)